# Plane curve whose all normal lines pass through origin is a circle

Tags: circles, curves, curvature

Assume that $α$ is a regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and all the normal lines of the curve pass though the origin. Prove that $α$ is contained in a circle around the origin. (Recall the normal line at $α(t)$ is the line through $α(t)$ pointing in the direction of the normal vector $N(t)$.)

If I can prove that the curvature is constant, then it would be solved, but I don't know how to do that. Any hint or suggestion?

**Note:** There is an old answer similar to this one, but it wasn't solved using the curvature. Also, it is not well explained from my point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbf r(t)$ be the curve. The tangent vector to the curve at $\mathbf r(t)$ is $\dot {\mathbf r}(t)$.

The normal to the curve at $\mathbf r(t)$ is a line that passes through $\mathbf r(t)$. If it also passes through the origin, then it has direction vector $\mathbf r(t) - \mathbf 0 = \mathbf r(t)$.

But it is also perpendicular to the tangent vector $\dot {\mathbf r}(t)$. That is, $$\dot {\mathbf r} \cdot \mathbf r = 0$$

Now, integrate with respect to $t$.

Comment: How can I integrate that? I'm using integration by parts but I think that what I am getting is wrong

Comment: Note that $x, y, z$ are independent functions of $t$.$$\int_0^T \mathbf r \cdot \dot {\mathbf r}\,dt = \int_0^Tx\frac {dx}{dt} + y\frac{dy}{dt} + z \frac{dz}{dt} \, dt$$

Comment: I have been working in it today, but sorry, I am not understading it. Why do we have x,y and z if we are working with $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't look back and recall this was 2-dimensional. You can drop $z$. If you are having trouble integrating $\int x \frac {dx}{dt}\, dt$ and $\int y \frac {dy}{dt}\, dt$, then you need to review the very basics. It is substitution you should be looking at, not integration by parts.

Comment: Ok, now I understand.  tried by parts with the first one, not separating it in x,y,z. Thank you so much for your help